# Merge using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have 2 data tables emp and division.

```
emp <- data.table(id=1:10, name=sample(LETTERS,10), dept=1:3)

division <- data.table(id=1, dept=1:5, name=c("Dept1","Dept2","Dept3","Dept4","Dept5"))

setkey(emp,dept)

setkey(division,dept)
```

I want to merge emp and division by not using "merge". I want only those rows in emp (left join). I also want the new column "DeptName" added. How can I do it?

Comment: `division[emp]`? This is one of the first things covered in the introductory material for `data.table`: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: `Frank` is right. Also, check out the `nomatch` parameter to filter out the non matches.

Comment: Frank - thanks for the link. I was actually trying emp[division] and getting an error.